# String concatenation in variables

Tags: python

## BACKGROUND:

I have set an excel parse the loads into “ObjectGroup” and “ObjectGroupMember”

```
ObjectGroup: [List of Objects]
```

Eg: SensitiveObject [‘PCI_SENS_OBJECT’, ‘SOX_SENS_OBJECT’]

```
ObjectGroupMember: [List of Members of ‘ObjectGroup]
```

Eg: PCI = [CC1,CC2,CCARD]

The variable name for the “ObjectGroupMember” is derived from values in ‘ObjectGroup’ using,

class GrpMem:

```
def __init__(self, senObj):
    for item in senObj:
        self.__dict__[item] = []`
```

My aim is to load my application with list of Objects and its respective members into my external database.

## EXPECTATION:

```
OBJECT_GROUP = DataParse('Datasheet.xlsx')
ObjectList = OBJECT_GROUP.senObj
ObjMem1 = OBJECT_GROUP.SenObjmem.PCI_SENS_OBJECT
```

1. Load external database with All Objects (senObj)
2. Load members for senObj(0). This is derived from SenObjmem.PCISENS_OBJECT

## ISSUE:

Hers is my current class

```
class LoadGrp():
    from GuardDataParse import DataParse
    def __init__(self,sourcefile):
        self.sourcefile = sourcefile
        self.parse = DataParse(self.sourcefile)
    def LoadGroup(self,GrpMembers):
        self.GrpMembers = GrpMembers
        DatasheetParse = DataParse(self.sourcefile)
        SensObj = DatasheetParse.senObj
        SensObjMem = DatasheetParse.SenObjmem+"."+str(GrpMembers)
       #code for application load
if __name__ == "__main__":
    grdapi_run = LoadGrp('DataSheet.xlsx')
```

## RUN:

```
grdapi_run = LoadGrp('DataSheet.xlsx')
grdapi_run.LoadGroup('PCI_SENS_OBJECT')
```

Based on the above logic when I provide the LoadGroup with value (eg. PCI_SENS_OBJECT), SensObjMem should end up looking like SensObjMem = DatasheetParse.SenObjmem.PCI_SENS_OBJECT
But I get the error” TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'str’”

Answer (score 0):

Python requires all string concatenation to be performed between explicit strings, unlike e.g. Java, which allows you to concatenate anything to a string. `DatasheetParse.SenObjmem` is presumably not a string, so you need to convert it to one using `str` before trying to concatenate it with `"."`.

Answer (score 0):

Python will not automatically convert types, even if that class has a `str` function defined, so when it gets to `DatasheetParse.SenObjmem+"."`, it attempts to call either `DatasheetParse.SenObjmem.add(".")` or `String.radd(DatasheetParse.SenObjmem)`, both of which are of course going to be undefined by default.

In order to fix this, you can either change it to `str(DatasheetParse.SenObjmem)+"."+str(GrpMembers)`, or overload the `add` function on `SenObjmem`, if you have access to it.

It might be better still to rewrite it as

```
"{}.{}".format(str(DatasheetParse.SenObjmem), str(GrpMembers)
```

I might also suggest reading up on [Difference between __str__ and __repr__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python).